# In Django, is the primary_key option ignored when a model is part of a Many to Many relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
class StateTax(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)
    rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    tax_regions = models.ManyToManyField(SalesTaxRegion, blank=True, null=True, related_name="accounts")
```

However the SQL Django creates during syncdb seems to ignore the primary_key option.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `airship_salestaxregion` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `abbr` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `rate` integer NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE `airship_account_tax_regions` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `account_id` integer NOT NULL,
    `salestaxregion_id` integer NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`account_id`, `salestaxregion_id`)
)
;
```

(note there is still an ID column in the first table and the relationship table references it)

Comment: This sql code for another table, not for StateTax

Answer (score 0):

As Like It says in the comment, you're getting your tables mixed up, you've given us python code for StateTax, not SalesTaxRegion.

I've tested your StateTax code with Django 1.4 and Postgres 9.2 and I get the following -

```
-- DROP TABLE testing_statetax;

CREATE TABLE testing_statetax
(
  name character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  abbr character varying(64) NOT NULL,
  rate integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT testing_statetax_pkey PRIMARY KEY (abbr)
)
```

There's no additional id field added.